# Detecting tab in chrome.cookies API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that manipulates cookie data. I'm using the cookies API to detect these changes:

```
chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(cookieData)
{
    if (cookieData.cause != "overwrite")
    {
       // perform action
    }
});
```

When the cookie change is detected, is there a way to detect on which tab it occurred? I've got multiple tabs open in my sample and the background service is firing it for every cookie, but I can't seem to differentiate between tabs.

Comment: Try observing changes to document.cookies in each tab's content script using [Object.observe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/).

Comment: This particular API does not expose such data.

Comment: @wOxxOm That might accomplish what I need.  Can I observe changes to ANY and ALL cookies or do I have to bind it to specific objects?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it, otherwise I'd post it as an answer.